# Displaying GUI Application in Docker Container on Windows 10 Host Without Linux Servers

Tags: windows, user-interface, docker, windows-10

I'm trying to dockerize a Windows 10 GUI application with a Windows 10 host, in a container that has microsoft/nanoserver as the base.

Currently I have the application installed in the same directory as my dockerfile, I add it to my docker context and run it no problem, except that the GUI never displays.

It seems that to display the GUI I would have to use a server (like in this case: [Windows 10 Docker Host - Display GUI application from Linux Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40024892/windows-10-docker-host-display-gui-application-from-linux-container)) but because I'm not using a linux container but rather a windows container the stuff about X11 server doesn't seem relevant.

**How would I configure my display settings for a GUI application in a pure windows set up?**

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51844304/how-to-setup-the-vb6-ide-in-a-docker-container-on-windows

Answer (score 15):

Containerizing Windows GUI apps is not currently supported. Details:

- [Access Windows 2016 Server Container (Docker container) via GUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35652644/access-windows-2016-server-container-docker-container-via-gui)
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f4314bc8-52d0-477c-9ecc-86a578b53814/no-support-expected-for-rdp-in-containers-for-windows-server-2016?forum=windowscontainers

Comment: Its been over 4 years, just curious is it possible to Containerize Windows GUI apps on Windows containers now?