# docker displaying a windows app on windows server core container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

I would like to display a basic windows application (an exe file)  using Docker in windows server core container. Manage to display it on my host machine when running it from the command prompt. However, when I tried it using windows server core container, the application didn't appear. Is the reason due to missing dll? Thank you very much for your help.

[Expected output to be displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZqvX.png)
[Output displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GV5eu.png)

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore

 WORKDIR /myapp

 COPY MyWinApp.exe /myapp


 ENTRYPOINT [ "CMD" ]
```

Comment: Windows Containers do not support GUI apps. I don't think what you are trying to do is currently possible.

Comment: Hi @Ragesh , thanks for the reply. Do you know the reason why it dosen't support GUI apps? Any reliable resources where i can view from ? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not really sure what the technical reasons are. Maybe the links in https://stackoverflow.com/a/40251175/34985 will be useful.